# Trying to test Angular with Karma/Jasmine, but can't get the Jasmine tests to set $scope correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

My Angular script looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);



app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test= "TEST";
});
```

My test file looks like this:

```
describe('first test', function() {
 var $scope;

  beforeEach(function (){
    module('myApp');

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('TestController', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    });
  it('scope should have test', function() {
    expect($scope.test).toEqual("TEST");
  });
});
```

This test fails saying $scope.test is undefined. I debugged in Chrome and saw that $scope has a bunch of properties on it, but none of them are test. I've looked through several examples online, and they all look pretty similar to this. i'm not quite sure what i'm doing wrong here and i'm stuck....

**edit**
I tried adding $controller to inject, but i'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Where do you think you will get `$controller`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass [`$controller` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) alongside with `$rootScope`:

```
inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('TestController', {
        $scope: $scope
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem even after adding $controller

Comment: When you debugged did you check if the controller code is executed? (Add console.log inside controller definition and verify)

Comment: No it's not. I see that var app = "..." is run, but my controller code is not

Comment: @user3715648 FYI, I've reproduced the issue you had, adding `$controller` solved it for me. Then, I've posted an answer.

Comment: @alecxe I tried copying your answer but i'm still having the same problem.